# Redirect permanent string replacement

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I would like the URL:

```
https://example.com/en/category/post+name_tour123456
```

To point to:

```
https://example.com/en/category/post+name+123456
```

I want to delete `_tour`

Can I do it with .htaccess?

I have created a regex to match all of these links:

```
((http[s]?):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([^_]+(?=_)*)(\W?_tour?)([0-9]*)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just match on the request. Try this rule and see how it works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /en/category/(.+)\+(.+)\+_tour(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/category/%1+%2+%3 [R=301,L]
```